# Nested Includes in C++

Tags: c++, header

I have a main file with about 7 header files.

The problem is that the structure is the following one:

--- main:  include a,b,c

---- b:  include a

---- c:  include a,b

I need this structure, since in one file I define some structures that are used by the main and other headers...

But the results is "multiple definition of xxxx", even using ifndef

How to solve it ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please consider putting some snippets of code in order for someone to be able to help you. Best Regards.

Comment: Without seeing a [mre] demonstrating this issue, I think the only sure answer is to remove all definitions from your header files. (Since you probably do not find this answer acceptable, may I suggest adding at least the definition of whatever "xxxx" represents? If that definition lives in "a", a MRE might consist of header files that include each other, plus the definition of xxxx in a, plus two source files that include c.)

Answer (score 1):

In C, This is usually solve by using conditional definition in the header file:

```c
#ifndef MYAPP_HEADER_A
#define MYAPP_HEADER_A 

typedef struct bla {...} bla;
...
..
#endif
```

**Edited** to obey rule told by @Konrad_Rudolph

Comment: The question is tagged C++, and names starting with leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter, as well as names containing two underscores, are reserved by the implementation, and are illegal to use.

Comment: FYI, this technique is known as "include guards".